# VBA To Clear Content

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code already but I want to know if this code can be altered or if there is a code that can check to see if a cell in the column E is empty and clear contents in a cell in column A if the someone exits the row

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 5 Then
    If Target.Value = vbEmpty Then
      Cells(Target.Row, 1).ClearContents
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Someone exits the row"? I tested this code and it checks for changes on column E. If it is changed to `vbEmpty` (or blank) it deletes the value at the same row at column A.

Comment: If I understand you right: Try `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange` instead.

Comment: I have a code in place already that puts the date in column A if I click anywhere in the row. What I want to do is clear contents if there is nothing in E and I leave the row. Right now the code only deletes if I put something in E and delete it or if I click it and attempt to type I want it to check and see anything is in E cleared automatically without going in to the cell in column E and delete what's in the cell in column A

Comment: @Jochen When I added the selection change it only clears when its in column A when I click inside the row I want it to clear content in column A when I click outside of the row and sees the cell in Column E is empty

Answer (score 1):

**Edited as per DirkReichel suggestion**
Add this formula in A1:

```
=IF(E1="","",IF(LEN(A1),A1,TODAY()))
```

Now drag it down in your column **"A"** as far as you need. It will add today's date in column **"A"** if there is a value in column **"E"**. Otherwise column **"A"** will remain empty

Comment: first: why `date(year(now()),...`? with the correct formatting just `now()` would do (also would `today()`)... second: the date will be volatile... opening the wb next day will change all dates in column A to the *actual* day...

Comment: @DirkReichel : Yup, you are right. I had forgot about `Today`. But as you mentioned, the date will change the next day so this approach wont work. I'll remove my answer

Comment: Turn on iteration and run for A1 `=IF(E1="","",IF(LEN(A1),A1,TODAY()))` (can be copied down) ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel : your answer, I'm not taking credit for that :). All yours mate

Comment: I've just changed the `ISBLANK($E1)` to `E1=""` which is the same, this also goes for the `DATE(YEAR(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()), DAY(NOW()))` change to `TODAY()`... the only new part is `IF(LEN(A1),A1,`... looking at it: 66% of the formula is your work :D

Comment: @DirkReichel there you go mate. Although, I don't think OP is interested in this solution anyway

Comment: Hey everyone the code that I got from @Mocair works but it kind of cancels out the single click event anywhere in the row I already have that puts the date into column A is there away I can get that back keep the code it makes it so I have to put something into column E for the code for the date I had before to work

Answer (score 0):

The first bit of your code checks for changes on column E to clear the column A.

So we just need to do the same thing again, but checking if column E is empty when changing column A.

This way, if you change the value on Column A and, at the same row, Column E is empty, it clears what you entered.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Target.Column = 5 Then
        If Target.Value = vbEmpty Then
           Cells(Target.Row, 1).ClearContents
        End If
     Elseif Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = vbEmpty Then
           Cells(Target.Row, 1).ClearContents
        End If
     End If
 End Sub
```

Edit: So, after your comment, here is how you should use your code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Target.Column = 5 Then
        If Target.Value = vbEmpty Then
           Cells(Target.Row, 1).ClearContents
        Else
           'Insert here whatever code you got on the single click event (Except the sub and end sub)
        End If
     Elseif Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = vbEmpty Then
           Cells(Target.Row, 1).ClearContents
        End If
     End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hey everyone the code that I got from @Mocair works but it kind of cancels out the single click event anywhere in the row I already have that puts the date into column A is there away I can get that back keep the code it makes it so I have to put something into column E for the code for the date I had before to work

Comment: It will cancel unless column E has data on it. Otherwise it will work. You can use the same code for worksheet Change to do the single click code. I'll edit the answer to show where

Comment: The edit will check: If you change column E to empty, It will erase the value on column A. If you change column E to something else that ISNT empty, it will run the code.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Target.Column = 5 Then
        If Target.Value = vbEmpty Then
           Cells(Target.Row, 1).ClearContents
        Else
         Cells(Target.Row, 1) = Date
        End If
     ElseIf Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = vbEmpty Then
           Cells(Target.Row, 1).ClearContents
        End If
     End If
 End Sub

Comment: would that be the code sorry about the format it change once I entered it into the comment box

Comment: That is the worksheet Change code, not the worksheet single click code

Comment: The single click code is pasted where you asked me to put it after else if

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155106/discussion-between-moacir-and-marquism).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get information of the "last" selection upon a change.... but there isn't a build-in solution. With a global variable, you still can do like this:

```
Dim oldTarget As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If oldTarget Is Nothing Then GoTo e
  If oldTarget.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    Dim x As Range
    For Each x In oldTarget.Rows
      If x.Cells(1, 5).Value = "" Then x.Cells(1, 1).Value = ""
    Next
  Else
    If oldTarget.Cells(1, 5).Value = "" Then oldTarget.Cells(1, 1).Value = ""
  End If
e:  Set oldTarget = Target.EntireRow
End Sub
```

As you see: `Dim oldTarget As Range` is outside of the sub. This way the set value/object stays until VBA get's stopped (closing the workbook / directly reset vba)

Comment: Hey everyone the code that I got from @Mocair works but it kind of cancels out the single click event anywhere in the row I already have that puts the date into column A is there away I can get that back keep the code it makes it so I have to put something into column E for the code for the date I had before to work